# conditional rendering with '&&' not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render the "Icon" component when the selectedTemplateIds length is greater than 0. Instead, 0 is being rendered on the screen and when the length is greater than 0 the icon doesn't display at all. Is there something I am misunderstanding with conditional rendering via a double ampersand.

Thank you!

```
<PanelWithHeader
          icon="propertyThree"
          title="Property Templates"
          marginTop
          suffixNode={
            <div className="flex-grow-1 d-flex justify-content-end">
              {selectedTemplateIds.length && <Icon icon="trash" />}
              {data?.property?.can_create_task_templates && (
                <FillOrOutlineButton
                  icon="trash"
                  buttonType="fill"
                  buttonSize="normal"
                  icon="addition"
                  buttonText="Template"
                  clickAction={() => setCreateTemplateOpen(true)}
                />
              )}
            </div>
          }
        >
```

Comment: You are mentioning *the selectedTemplateIds length is greater than 0* . So change `selectedTemplateIds.length` to `selectedTemplateIds.length > 0` .. Like `{selectedTemplateIds.length > 0 && <Icon icon="trash" />}`

Answer (score 0):

Either change it to `selectedTemplateIds.length > 0` or `!!selectedTemplateIds.length`. That will prevent the 0 from displaying.
As for the Icon not displaying at all, it might be that the Icon is not imported properly.